# How to access a deployed smart contract attributes using web3.eth.contract(abi,address) in python

Tags: solidity, ropsten, web3.py, python

```
web3 = Web3(provider=HTTPProvider(http://ropsten.infura.io/v4/API_KEY)
abi = '[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_utxoPos","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_txBytes","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_proof","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_sigs","type":"bytes"}],"name":"startExit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_cUtxoPos","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_eUtxoIndex","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_txBytes","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_proof","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_sigs","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_confirmationSig","type":"bytes"}],"name":"challengeExit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"exits","outputs":[{"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"name":"token","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_token","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"startFeeExit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"srcTokenAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"destTokenAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"sendToUserAddresss","type":"address"},{"name":"maxDestAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"minConversionRate","type":"uint256"}],"name":"depositKyberTokens","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"operator","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"currentChildBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_token","type":"address"}],"name":"finalizeExits","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_blockNumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getChildChain","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_token","type":"address"}],"name":"getNextExit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"CHILD_BLOCK_INTERVAL","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"currentDepositBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_root","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"submitBlock","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getDepositBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"currentFeeExit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"exitsQueues","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_utxoPos","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getExit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_depositPos","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_token","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"startDepositExit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"childChain","outputs":[{"name":"root","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"depositor","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"depositBlock","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"exitor","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"utxoPos","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ExitStarted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"root","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BlockSubmitted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"token","type":"address"}],"name":"TokenAdded","type":"event"}]'
contract_instance = web3.eth.contract(address, abi=abi)
currentChild = contract_instance.CHILD_BLOCK_INTERVAL.call()
```

Trying to connect my [smart contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc0d813BeF0BA42e1C6ec44e290ba9481FE7f420E) in Python and access attributes deployed on Ropsten but getting error:

> AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute
>   'CHILD_BLOCK_INTERVAL'

Comment: just looking at your ABI, it looks it is a wrong one, there is no definition for CHILD_BLOCK_INTERVAL

Comment: its a constant member variable of unsigned integer data type mentioned in ABI. Did you say it must be defined or initiated with some value in ABI too ?

Answer (score 1):

From the ABI's perspective, public attributes are just like functions, so you use the [function call syntax](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction), like:

```
contract_instance.functions.CHILD_BLOCK_INTERVAL.call()
```

Comment: requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ropsten.infura.io', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)

updated web3.py => 4.6.0 in Python 
changed timeout from 10s to 30s => provider=HTTPProvider('http://ropsten.infura.io/v4/API_KEY', request_kwargs={'timeout': 30})

but still same error following you 
while my [smart contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc0d813bef0ba42e1c6ec44e290ba9481fe7f420e)

Comment: Have you tried with another node besides Infura? Maybe a local geth or parity in light mode?

Comment: found that I can get blocks, transactions on "geth attach localhost:8545". but i wanted to access blocks created only on deployed smart contract on ropsten. Is there any tutorial or helping material to follow and get blocks created.